# ReactJs feedback with SVG Emojis

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

[image]`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Button from "../../elements/buttons/Button";
import Icon from "../../elements/icons/Icon";


function useDynamicSVGImport(name, options = {}) {
  const ImportedIconRef = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const { onCompleted, onError } = options;
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const importIcon = async () => {
      try {
        ImportedIconRef.current = (
          await import(`./${name}.svg`)
        ).ReactComponent;
        if (onCompleted) {
          onCompleted(name, ImportedIconRef.current);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        if (onError) {
          onError(err);
        }
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name, onCompleted, onError]);

  return { error, loading, SvgIcon: ImportedIconRef.current };
}

/**
 * Simple wrapper for dynamic SVG import hook. You can implement your own wrapper,
 * or even use the hook directly in your components.
 */
 /** const Icon = ({ name, onCompleted, onError, ...rest }) => {
  const { error, loading, SvgIcon } = useDynamicSVGImport(name, {
    onCompleted,
    onError
  });
  if (error) {
    return error.message;
  }
  if (loading) {
    return "Loading...";
  }
  if (SvgIcon) {
    return <SvgIcon {...rest} />;
  }
  return null;
};
*/
export default function FacialReactions() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("svg1");

  const handleOnCompleted = useCallback(
    (iconName) => console.log(`${iconName} successfully loaded`),
    []
  );

  const handleIconError = useCallback((err) => console.error(err.message), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setName((prevName) => (prevName === "svg1" ? "svg2" : "svg1"))
        }
      >
        Change Icon
      </button>
      <section>
      <Icon icon="mood-vgood" variant="horizontal" />
      <Icon icon="mood-good" variant="horizontal" />
      <Icon icon="mood-neutral" variant="horizontal" />
      <Icon icon="mood-bad" variant="horizontal" />
      <Icon icon="mood-vbad" variant="horizontal" />
         
/** now i had to change the entire functionality to fit the attached Picture in the head of the question! */
/**
        <Icon
          name={name}
          fill="gray"
          onCompleted={handleOnCompleted}
          onError={handleIconError}
        />
        <Icon
          name="svg1"
          fill="gray"
          width="300"
          onCompleted={handleOnCompleted}
          onError={handleIconError}
        />
        <Icon
          name="svg2"
          fill="darkblue"
          height="100"
          onCompleted={handleOnCompleted}
          onError={handleIconError}
        />
*/
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`[image]

I have been struggling with implementing the functionality of the attached design, a react feedback reaction using predefined SVG facial icons . But I can not figure out from where to start.
I have already the Icon set ready to use, however, I do not know how to come up with such functionality, How to add these SVG icons into a reusable react component!. now I had to change the entire functionality to fit the attached Picture in the head of the question!

please any help with that matter will be deeply appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just add onClick functionality to the svg.

```
<path onClick={()=>setMood(1)}></path>
```

For adding svg to react/jsx you can take a look at this https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/

Comment: will you please check the edition of the question once more , maybe you could help me with my issue !